# Why web dashboard so slow after i deploying a stream or task

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm new to Spring Cloud Data Flow.Web dashboard seems so slow after deployed a stream or task.What's the reason?
I built the local machine on windows as the official guide.
https://dataflow.spring.io/getting-started/

I tried restart docker but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there could be many reasons for the slow responsiveness of the SCDF dashboard. Here are some of the things you can check:

- Check if you have sufficient resources in your docker setup (CPU & memory)
- Check if the slowness is related to the backend doing some operation (downloading the application artifact etc., this is especially true for local setup)

Comment: For more information on resource constraints and SCDF docker setup, you can check this thread: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3349#issuecomment-512587874

Comment: i have changed the setting of docker.CPU:4 Memory:8G.But it doesn't work,stream deploying still slow.And i notice Docker.Service and docker-compose.exe only cost a little memory that no more than 100 MB.Do i need edit the docker-compose.yml?

Comment: No, docker setup should be fine. Does the slowness occur only when you deploy the stream but otherwise things look normal? Would you mind sharing some log of the operations during the slowness?

Comment: I have deployed a stream and get into runtime successful by [guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/data-flow-stream/#local).And i notice the sender's log shows  `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`. If i use java -jar to run the sender app ,the exception didn't occur.  What's the reason?